# How do I find out eigenvectors corresponding to a particular eigenvalue of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvector, eigenvalue

How do I find out eigenvectors corresponding to  a particular eigenvalue?

I have a stochastic matrix(P), one of the eigenvalues of which is 1. I need to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

The scipy function [**scipy.linalg.eig**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) returns the array  of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

```
D, V = scipy.linalg.eig(P)
```

Here D(array of values) and V(array of vectors) are both vectors.

One way is to do a search in D and extract the corresponding eigenvector in V. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for one eigenvector corresponding to one eigenvalue,  it could be much more efficient to use the [scipy.sparse.linalg implementation of the eig function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#matrix-factorizations).
It allows to look for a fixed number of eigenvectors and to shift the search around a specific value. You could do for instance :

```
values, vectors = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(P, k=1, sigma=1)
```

Comment: Does it return the left eigenvalue of P?

Comment: I think you meant eigs not eig. I tried with scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs(P, k=1, sigma=1) but an exception is raised -
    raise NotImplementedError("shifted eigenproblem not supported yet")

Comment: Fixed eig -> eigs. Shifted  eigenproblem is implemented in the version I use : scipy 0.10.1

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg


P = np.array([[2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 3]])

D, V = linalg.eig(P)
print(D)
# [ 2.  1.  3.]
```

The eigenvectors are columns of V:

```
V = V.T

for val, vec in zip(D, V):
    assert np.allclose(np.dot(P, vec), val*vec)
```

So the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1.0 is

```
def near(a, b, rtol = 1e-5, atol = 1e-8):
    return np.abs(a-b)<(atol+rtol*np.abs(b))

print(V[near(D, 1.0)])
# [[ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

Since there can be more than one eigenvector with the same eigenvalue, `V[near(D, 1.0)]` returns a 2-dimensional array -- each row of the array is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue of 1.0.